# Sort an array of string or integers in a specific format

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, sorting

I need to sort an array in the following form:

**Input**
[904, 917, 945, 998, 9, 82, 43, 1112, 99, 97, 93]

**Output**
[9, 99, 998, 97, 945, 93, 917, 904, 88, 32, 1112]

The sorting rule is (max first digit, max second digit, max third digit, ....) and the smaller length number will be kept first in case of clash.

Eg. in 9 and 998 , 9 will come first as the first digit is the same but it has less number of digits.

It will be great if I can apply the logic as a key in sorting function in Python.

**Update**

I was actually trying to solve this question on Leetcode:
https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-number/

To solve it, I needed that kind of sorting function which I modified to finally solve the question using this:

```
nums = [904, 917, 945, 998, 9, 82, 43, 1112, 99, 97, 93]
nums = [str(i) for i in nums]
n = max(map(len,nums))
nums = sorted(nums, key = lambda x : (x.ljust(n,x[0]), x[-1]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what hasn't worked about that? Be specific.

Comment: The input and output lists don't even have the same integers.

Comment: @Jab yeah, I corrected that.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I didn't try anything, I was looking for the fastest and cleanest way to implement this kind of sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a function called spec_sort:

```
def spec_sort(l):
    l_str=map(str,l)
    n=max(map(len,l_str))
    return sorted(l,key=lambda i:(str(i).ljust(n,'a')),reverse=True)
```

and here is the example:

```
i=[904, 917, 945, 998, 9, 82, 43, 1112, 99, 97, 93]
spec_sort(i)
```

the output should be:

```
[9, 99, 998, 97, 945, 93, 917, 904, 82, 43, 1112]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, I modified your function to solve the actual problem.

Answer (score 5):

A bit hacky but is this what you're looking for?

```
sorted(yourlist, key=lambda x: ''.join([str(9-int(y)) for y in str(x)]))
```

Comment: converting back to string is not needed. `lambda x: [9-int(y) for y in str(x)]`

Comment: @wjandrea Neither is the `9` then.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted, but @A.Tangs solution is 4 times faster than this one.